# Will the Code continue to be executed if an error in caught using try{}catch{}

Tags: java, android, exception, nullpointerexception, try-catch

I am using `try{}catch{}` in my Android app to catch Null Pointer exception.

This is my code

```
public class load extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        public Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {


            try {
                Function_A();
            }
            catch (NullPointerException e ){

            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void n) {
            super.onPostExecute(n);

        }
```

And this is the `Function_A()` code

```
 public void Function_A()
{
   for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
       //Some code which might trigger Null Pointer exception some times
    }

}
```

My Question is suppose I execute the `AsyncTask` and the `doInBackground` calls a method wrapping it in `try{}catch{}`. Now if the `for loop` in the `Function_A()` is at `i` = 70 and it throws an Null Pointer Exception which is caught by `try{}catch{}`, will the for loop continue to be executed till the value of `i` reaches 99  or will it stop there itself and the `onPostExecute` will be called and the `AsyncTask` will end.

Comment: If function_A throws exception, that means the code has exited the function call and is back to doInBackground method. so, the loop wouldn't continue.

Comment: @AvinashAnand Thanks for the replying. Can you please post an answer so that I can accept it. Just to reclarify `Function_A` will exit on Null Pointer Exception even if the function was called using `try{]catch{}`?

Comment: It's better to code defensively than catch NPEs.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Thanks. I believe you are extremely right, but in my case it wont make any difference if the Null Pointer exception is caught as this is for an notification to be shown but is not important. I will put up another question very soon to try to solve that Null Pointer Exception as I get this error while loading the list of all the Files in the Phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Function_A` throws exception and there is no try catch clause inside it, the exception will propagate to the caller i.e. `doInBackground`. Now, you could do few things here.

1. Like @ChiefTwoPencils said, code defensively so that no `NullPointerException` is thrown.
2. If you really want to catch it and still the loop should continue, then put `try-catch` inside the loop.

Ideally, I would suggest, write code that doesn't throw null pointer. Always check for null before calling something on it. Or try `Optional` from Java 8 to wrap objects that you think could be null. Here is link to JavaDoc -
[Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should never catch null pointer exceptions because it is a RunTimeException and your code should not allow such a situation. It shows that there is a bug in your code to fix.  If your code logic can not recover from null pointer exception at run time, do not try to catch it.

Comment: Thanks. I believe you are extremely right, but in my case it wont make any difference if the Null Pointer exception is caught as this is for an notification to be shown but is not important. I will put up another question very soon to try to solve that Null Pointer Exception as I get this error while loading the list of all the Files in the Phone.